# .htaccess redirect from subdomain to subdirectory AND https rules

Tags: .htaccess

I have two different localizations of my website.

1) The first is an English language version: www.example.com

2) The second is a Spanish language version: es.example.com

I am moving the Spanish langauge version to to www.example.com/ES

My current .htaccess file redirects calls to example.com to www.example.com like this:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now I want to add to that to redirect my subdomain to a subdirectory, so I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/ES/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But that seems to direct all calls to es.example.com to www.example.com and not to www.example.com/ES

Any suggestions?

EDIT: FULL .htaccess ADDED BELOW:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/ES/$1 [R=301,L]




 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]





<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# Flash
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>





<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
  </FilesMatch>



  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html|svg|swf)$">
      Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>





<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-shockwave-flash
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype

# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>




ErrorDocument 400 /400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html`
```

Comment: Your rules look like they should work. Did you clear your browser cache ?

Comment: @starkeen - Good tip, thanks. I tried in an incognito window and now I get one compounded URL: https://www.example.com/https://www.example.com/ES/  I'm not an .htaccess guy at all. Is there some way to to an "IF/ ELSE IF" kind of thing? Thanks again.

Comment: Try adding `L` flag to your first rule. `[R=301,L]` and then clear your browser cache once again to test it.

Comment: Good thought. Thanks again, @starkeen. But that didn't help either. It still bounces back to www.example.com

Comment: What folder is your subdomain pointing to and what is the location of your htaccess?

Comment: subdomain es.example.com points to www.example.com/ES.  The .htaccess is in the root of www.example.com.

Comment: Ok, Do you also have an htaccess in the `ES` folder? If yes then place your subdomain rules in that htaccess just to see what results it yealds

Comment: @starkeen No, there are no other htaccess files...  but this might provide some insight: Currently if I enter "es.example.com/someFile.html" the htaccess correctly redirects to www.example.com/ES/someFile.html *but* if I enter just "es.example.com" without any specific file, it bounces me to www.example.com (without the /ES directory). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Can you post your full htaccess contents in the question?

Comment: Full htaccess added to question text. Thanks.

Comment: Your htaccess rules are fine and I don't think the problem is being caused by the htaccess. I think the problem is elsewhere.  If `es.example.com/` serves you the homepage of your maindomain then perhaps there is something wrong with your subdomain setup or maybe the redirection is happening from your client side code  (javasccript) or php redirect.